# create own local Java Identity Provider SAML2

Tags: localhost, saml-2.0

I have to create XML metadata response for Service provider consume it. The problem is the SP is not conventional and the project is private.

1. user log on application with form
2. When we want to access to external SP (module from our application) we generate the XML SAML2 metadata and inject it in IFRAME as a local IDP
3. The SAML ticket is consumed by the external application and give us ticket to inject in IFRAME

I make SP and IDP work with openID. It is great but we need create the SAML xml locally so we have to code our IDP from scratch. We used j2ee (wildfly war ...) we don't have spring.

We saw shibboleth but could not access to their repository, and there is no local tutorial using maven anywhere.

Any idea ?